# correct way to free m*n matrix bidimensional allocation

Tags: c, matrix

I allocate a non-square matrix in this way, but I'm not sure if I'm using the deallocation correctly

```
float **matrix_alloc(int m /* rows */, int n /* columns */)
{
    int i;
    float **arr = malloc(m*sizeof(*arr));
    for(i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        arr[i]=malloc(n*sizeof(**arr));
    }
    return arr;
}
```

I have tried two way to free the memory

**-Attempt A** loop **rows**

```
void free_mem_mat(int m, float **array) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);
}
```

**- Attempt B** loop **columns**

```
void free_mem_mat(int n, float **array) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);
}
```

what should I use to free? the way **A** on the rows or the way **B**? (I know as written the method is the same I have rewritten this to be most clear possible)

Comment: Ask yourself: What does the allocation function loop over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need one `free()` for each `malloc()`<sup>*</sup>.  There were `m+1` calls to `malloc()`; you'd better make `m+1` calls to `free()` too.

Given that as the starting point, option A is the correct solution.  However, it is also fair to note that the two functions (option A and option B) are strictly equivalent as long as you pass the `m` dimension given to the allocation function as the size argument of the deallocation function.  The comment in option B is misleading; you're not looping over columns.

Given:

```
enum { MAT_ROWS = 20, MAT_COLS = 30 };
float **matrix = matrix_alloc(MAT_ROWS, MAT_COLS);
```

The correct call to `free_mem_mat()` is:

```
free_mem_mat(MAT_ROWS, matrix);
```

---

<sup>* This is an over-simplified statement if you use `realloc()` or `calloc()`.  You need a `free()` for each `malloc()` that was not `realloc()`'d, and a `free()` for each `realloc()` that did not do a `free()` — by setting the size to 0.  Treat `calloc()` as equivalent to `malloc()` as far as `free()` is concerned.</sup>

Comment: Ok thank you! Another little doubt. Suppose I must use various matrix operations methods in sequence to get a final result e.g. `OPERATION_FINAL_RES=OPERATION1_RES+OPERATION2_RES`*OPERATION3_RES, and each operation allocate a different matrix per result. I should deallocate the memory of each partial result matrix only at the end of OPERATION_FINAL_RES. Right? Or could I deallocate the result memory of each matrix result after the end of the respective method?

Comment: You can release the result after you've finished using it (not before).  Your expression `R = A + B * C` (shortening the matrix names a bit), might be written as: `float **T = mat_mul(B, n2, m2, C, n3, m3); float **R = mat_add(A, n1, m1, T, n2, m3);` and you might free `T` after that.  You might also want to think about creating a structure to hold the matrix with its dimensions and the pointer so that you don't have to deduce the correct size of the output of `mat_mul()`.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that it has many allocations

I prefer this mode

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float **matrix_alloc(int m /* rows */, int n /* columns */)
{
        int i;

        float **arr = malloc(m * sizeof(float *));
        *(arr) = malloc(m * n * sizeof(float));

        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                *(arr + i) = (*(arr) + i * n);
        }

        return arr;
}

void free_mem_mat(float **array) {
        free(*(array));
        free(array);
}

int main () {

        float **matrix = matrix_alloc(10, 20);
        free_mem_mat(matrix);

        return 0;
}
```

more information in:
http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html

Answer (score 0):

arr was allocated as an array of m elements, each a pointer to some allocated memory. Therefore, you must free the m pointers in arr.   In freeing each, you don't need to mention the size of the thing pointed to.

Comment: emmm. I'm not sure of understanding, in other words, is right A, B, there is a way better then both or are both right? XD