# How to correctly deallocate c matrices used in composite operations

Tags: c, memory-management

In a task I use various base matrix methods e.g.

-multiply
-transpose
-invert
-triangularize

every methos use `matrx_memory_alloc(float **m,int row, int col)` to allocate the memory for result matrix

now I have a method that in pseudo-code do something like this

```
float **final_function(float matrix, int row, int col){
   float **result= invert(multiply(matrix,transpose(matrix, int row, int col),  int row, int col)
   return result
}
```

I have also a  method  `matrx_memory_dealloc(float **m, int row, int col)` that deallocates the memory in the analogous way was allocated.

Now:

How should I correctly deallocate every memory allocation done in each of the methods related to `final_function`? In others words: when should I call the deallocation method?

If I call the deallocation method after `final_function`, as far as I know should deallocate only the last allocation used in final function not all the previous allocations of the related methods. Am I wrong?

Comment: It's not clear from your posted code how and where you use the memory you allocate. It's hard to suggest anything meaningful without seeing more of your code.

Comment: `matrx_memory_dealloc(int row, int col)`. This sounds somewhat wrong. Where's the matrix? Can you show the function? You probably should call it as many times as there are calls to allocation functions. If you chain expressions like `invert(multiply(matrix,transpose(matrix, int row, int col),  int row, int col)` it will be rather difficult to do, as e.g. you lose the result of `transpose` and can never deallocate it.

Comment: If each of those chained functions returns a new matrix *without* deallocating the passed-in matrix (which in itself is a questionable design) the posted code likely leaks like a sieve leaks rainwater. You hopefully have their code; we most-certainly *don't*. See what they do.

Comment: @r Sahu & n.mI use allocation in every matrix method, the implementation of allocation and deallocation, work itself, my problem is that: if I call deallocation after every method afaik I should lost the matrix needed to the final calculation, if I call deallocation after final probably will be deallocated only the last allocation

Comment: This question [Correct way to free m*n matrix bidimensional allocation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195654/correct-way-to-free-mn-matrix-bidimensional-allocation/24195772#comment37358379_24195772) is closely related.  There is discussion there about compound matrix expressions (not as compound as these ones, but getting there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you really meant some compilable code along the lines of:

```
float **invert(float **matrix, int row, int col);
float **transpose(float **matrix, int row, int col);
float **multiply(float **matrix1, int row1, int col1, float **matrix2, int row2, col2);

float **final_function(float **matrix, int row, int col)
{
   float **result = invert(multiply(matrix, row, col, transpose(matrix, row, col), row, col), row, col);
   return result;
}
```

(where the primary differences are losing the `int` in the line that invokes the 3 functions), then you are on a hiding to nothing as written.  There is no way to release the memory that was allocated by the functions.  You have to write the code more explicitly:

```
float **invert(float **matrix, int row, int col);
float **transpose(float **matrix, int row, int col);
float **multiply(float **matrix1, int row1, int col1, float **matrix2, int row2, col2);

float **final_function(float **matrix, int row, int col)
{
    float **t1 = transpose(matrix, row, col);
    float **t2 = multiply(matrix, row, col, t1, col, row);  // Dubious dimensions
    float **result = invert(t2, row, col);
    mtrix_memory_dealloc(t1, col, row);
    mtrix_memory_dealloc(t2, row, col);  // Dubious dimensions
    return result;
}
```

This code is more a case of 'the principle' than fully working code.  You need to know the size of the output matrices.  I've deduced that the output matrix for the transpose has (col x row) when the input is (row x col); I've not sat and thought about the size of the output of `multiply()` (but it is either (row x row) or (col x col) unless I'm completely off base).  In which case, the call to `invert()` is wrong — unless `row == col`; it should either be `invert(t2, row, row)` or `invert(t2, col, col)`.  The call to `mtrix_memory_dealloc(t2, …)` should likewise be fixed.

Clearly, you could free `t1` before calling `invert()`.

---

#### But my code still crashes?

You don't show us the `main()` or `transposeMatrix()` functions, so we can't tell why your code crashes.  The problem is not in your memory allocation or deallocation functions though.  Here they are embedded (unchanged) into a program with my implementation of your `transposeMatrix()` and a `matrix_print()` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern void matrix_print(const char *tag, int m, int n, float **matrix);

extern float **transposeMatrix(int m, int n, float **matrix);
extern float **matrx_memory_alloc(int m, int n);
extern void matrx_memory_dealloc(int m, float **array);

float **matrx_memory_alloc(int m, int n)
{
    int i;
    float **arr = malloc(m * sizeof(*arr));
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(**arr));
    }
    return arr;
}

void matrx_memory_dealloc(int m, float **array)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);
}

float **transposeMatrix(int m, int n, float **matrix)
{
    float **result = matrx_memory_alloc(n, m);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            result[j][i] = matrix[i][j];
    }
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    float **matrix = matrx_memory_alloc(3, 4);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = (i + j + 1) + ((9 - i - j) / 10.0);
    }

    matrix_print("Initial", 3, 4, matrix);
    float **transpose = transposeMatrix(3, 4, matrix);
    matrix_print("Transpose", 4, 3, transpose);
    matrx_memory_dealloc(4, transpose);
    matrx_memory_dealloc(3, matrix);

    return 0;
}

void matrix_print(const char *tag, int m, int n, float **matrix)
{
    int i, j;

    printf("%s (%d x %d):\n", tag, m, n);
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        char *pad = "[";
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%s%6.3f", pad, matrix[i][j]);
            pad = ", ";
        }
        printf("%s", " ]\n");
    }
}
```

It compiles cleanly under stringent compiler options:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wold-style-definition -Werror so24276121.c -o so24276121
```

I note that [`valgrind`](http://www.valgrind.org/) gives it a clean bill of health:

```
==34372== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==34372== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==34372== Using Valgrind-3.10.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==34372== Command: ./so24276121
==34372== 
Initial (3 x 4):
[ 1.900,  2.800,  3.700,  4.600 ]
[ 2.800,  3.700,  4.600,  5.500 ]
[ 3.700,  4.600,  5.500,  6.400 ]
Transpose (4 x 3):
[ 1.900,  2.800,  3.700 ]
[ 2.800,  3.700,  4.600 ]
[ 3.700,  4.600,  5.500 ]
[ 4.600,  5.500,  6.400 ]
==34372== 
==34372== HEAP SUMMARY:
==34372==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==34372==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 9 frees, 152 bytes allocated
==34372== 
==34372== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==34372== 
==34372== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==34372== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know very much about c matrices, but the memory you allocated will have addresses, so if you had the pointers to those addresses you should be able to deallocate them all using their names. 
Though I should hope that if your functions are returning matrix memory types then they should be being deleted at the end of each function on return. I think normal memory is passed via EAX or EAX:EBX combination, it is placed in register and then popped back off into your variable or something. But larger memory seems to be coded into a hidden pointer parameter that points to where the "RETURN" value will be stored by your function and then memory is read from there. 
So it might be easier for you to use a structure like this

```
matrix *M;

MatrixFunction( matrix* M, int rows, int columns);
```

or

```
MatrixFunction( matrix* M, matrix N, int rows, int columns)
```

and then code like this:

```
invert(Multiply(M,.....))))
```

that way there is only one M for which to create memory and only one M to destroy memory

Comment: I find this answer puzzling and confusing, yet also with the germs of a good idea.  The EAX:EBX commentary is puzzling; it is tightly tied to assembler-level x86 programming, which is not appropriate for this discussion of C.  The "if you have pointers ... deallocate them all using their names" commentary is confusing.  The section from "So it might be easier..." is the basis of a good idea, but there needs to be some fleshing out of details.  For example, the structure should include the rows and columns, so except for the create function, there'd be no need to pass explicit sizes.